# Recover saved over file in word 2003

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I recently saved a document over one of my homework in word. My text is now all gone and I can't find a way to get it back. I already tried to see if there was a revision history active or too Ctrl+Z ad infinitum with out any succes. Any idea of How I could get this my homework back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Vista and 7, my only suggestion is to go to the file in *Windows Explorer*, right-click it, select *Properties*, and look in the *Previous Versions* tab.

Good luck!