# How to recover data which was saved earlier in word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, recovery

My old uncle is working in his autobiography he just knows the basic things about MS Word. He wrote around 200 pages in 2yr. Yesterday he pressed ctrl+A(which he don't know and I guessed that had happened after listening to him) and then pressed backspace(in confusion) then he saw the blank page and saved the document.

Now I just want to know is there any method I can use to get the data.
I have tried the stellar recovery software but it shows the blank file which I have and didn't find the previous one and also tried many methods but no luck.

Please tell me any method which will work. He is very sad about it.

Comment: You have tried the only solution, attempting to find the fragments of a document, that still exists on the drive.  You don't indicate if the user enabled File History on the file, without something like File History, recovery file will be limited to what you have already attempted.  I assume no backups exist at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover saved over file in word 2003](https://superuser.com/questions/357118/recover-saved-over-file-in-word-2003)

Comment: yes there's no backup
and in Properties,  in the Previous Versions tab, it says there are no previous versions available.